# MS Word Equation Editor

Tags: math, ms-word, automation, editor

I need to add several commands from Equation editor (fraction, over bars, under bars, absolute value) into my custom application using embedded MS Word as an editor. It seems that this is not possible. Is there any way to add math symbols into word ?

Comment: Why not embed Equation Editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of your equations, I recommended [MathType](http://www.dessci.com/en/products/mathtype/) (with word) to a lot of people who wanted to write formulas down for homework without the knowledge of [TeX or LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/).

I still use LaTeX in Word, I take images from [Online LaTeX editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) and paste them in. Because Word's equation editor just plain sucks.

Comment: I need to restrict the number of actions the user allowed to do in the application.

Comment: You'll probably need to implement your own add-on then, it's difficult to lock down a word application for the type of input you're putting into it. By design, it's a word processor and limiting it too much doesn't make it a word processor anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other comment, these tasks are made simpler by using LaTeX, which after you get good at it is much faster than inputting equations into MS Word.

If you would like to edit equations in LaTeX, but still use MS Word for your reports, I recommend the [online equation editor at formulasheet.com](http://formulasheet.com/#r%7Ced). It gives you a live preview of the formula, but also the ability to 'Copy to Word' (it's a button on the editor) as long as your version of MS Word is 2007 or higher. When pasted into MS Word, the equation remains editable using the MS Word equation editor, unlike a still image. The live preview is a still image, so you can also copy and paste that if you prefer.